# Colorful input Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello i've been working with python for about two years, and I still have not figured out how to make a colorful input. For example:

```
                            what the user types would be green
                                            ↓
this would be blue or something--> Enter: (where user types)
```

So it would be like this just with the colors above:

```
x = input("Enter: ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I have answered my own question, what you can do is use color codes like this;

```
OKGREEN = '\033[92m'

x = input("Enter: "+OKGREEN)
```

this would make your input green but the text to the left the default color.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try [colorama](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/) lib:

[image]